# invert many small, different-sized matrices python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have a block-diagonal sparse matrix in python with hundreds of thousands to millions of rows, but with many different sized blocks between 1x1 and 6x6; for example plt.spy() on a submatrix: [image]

I need the inverse of this matrix without looping in python (too slow). I should be able to extract the block diagonal to get a list of 2d arrays (have not actually implemented this yet), but even then I cannot figure out how to apply, e.g., np.linalg.inv() to a bunch of different size matrices. Any ideas on inverting in sparse matrix form or via a list of diagonal blocks??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, **there is no way to do that efficiently using Numpy**. The best solution would be to group the blocks by size to compute them in a vectorized way (most Numpy function cannot work on array of different sizes). But this solution is not great because Numpy is not designed to compute small arrays and the overhead will be pretty big for such a small blocks.

A solution is to use **Numba** so to generate a fast native code to compute your blocks efficiently. Numba supports [typed lists](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html?highlight=dict#list) and [`np.linalg.inv`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/autogen_numpy_listing.html#numpy.linalg.inv). If your input is a sparse matrix the best solution would be to extract the sub-blocks directly from it. However, Numba does not supports the Scipy's sparse matrices yet. That being said, you can for example extract the `data` and `indices` fields (which are Numpy array) of a CSR matrix so to compute them using Numba although this is a bit more complex to do.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, will look into Numba. Hadn't thought to group blocks by size, but that could be doable. What do you mean by "Numpy is not designed to compute small arrays" though? Do you mean there are no built in optimizations for, say, 3x3 or 4x4 matrices, compared to a general dense inv formula? I only have to do it once, so this might be okay, the loop overhead is just too significant.

Comment: For small arrays, Numpy adds a quite big overheads that make the computation relatively slow compared to the size of the arrays. This is due to many checks, cases to consider, reference counting, argument parsing, etc. AFAIK, there is also no special optimization for eg. 3x3 or 4x4 matrices (that would not be very useful due to the overheads previously mentioned). Doing such optimization with Numba should help a lot.